# Translate Stripe placeholder

Tags: javascript, placeholder, translate

I need to translate the checkout stripe into my language (spanish).

I contacted with stripe and they answered me:

Hi there,

Thanks for writing in! We totally understand that offering our dashboard and Checkout in different language options is something that's really important to our users. We're working right now to get this ready to go live but I unfortunately don't have a roll-out date for it, though we'll definitely reach out to you when we have an update.

---

So I thought I could replace the placeholder text with javascript but does not work with the checkout (the form appears in a popup)

https://stripe.com/docs/checkout

Any idea?